# multi inherit from QObject and QRunnable error

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm using pyqt4.
I have a class multi inherited from QObject and QRunnable like this:

```
class DownloadTask(QObject, QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        QRunnable.__init__(self)
        self.setAutoDelete(False)
```

When an instance of DownloadTask is initializing, the last line throws exception:

```
TypeError: could not convert 'DownloadTask' to 'QRunnable'
```

But I think it is correct in grammer, QRunnable has the method setAutoDelete. Why can't it convert to QRunnable?

Update:
I intend to use QThreadPool to manage multi threads downloading resources from Internet, and emit a signal after finished. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PyQt reference guide > Things to be Aware Of > Multiple inheritance:](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/gotchas.html#multiple-inheritance)

> It is not possible to define a new Python class that sub-classes from more than one Qt class.

Comment: I intend to use QThreadPool to manage multi threads downloading resources from Internet, and emit a signal after finished. How can I do that?

Comment: @hbprotoss Please ask that as a separate question.