# Implementing QQuickAsyncImageProvider in Pyside; No such signal QObject::finished()

Tags: python, pyside, qtquick2

I'm attempting to implement a subclass of [`QQuickAsyncImageProvider`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickasyncimageprovider.html) in Pyside6, referring to the official [example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/examples/quick/imageresponseprovider). I'm already aware of the potential hurdle that, unlike in the C++ example code, with PySide it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134640/multi-inherit-from-qobject-and-qrunnable-error) to inherit from both `QRunnable` and `QObject`. In order to send a signal from my `QRunnable` I'm instead using an intermediary `QObject`, as suggested [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1131). That part works fine.

Here's my attempt so far at using this arrangement along with my own subclass of `QQuickAsyncImageProvider`:

```
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QImage
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QRunnable, QThreadPool, Signal
from PySide6.QtQuick import (QQuickImageResponse, QQuickAsyncImageProvider,
                             QQuickTextureFactory)

class Signaller(QObject):
    done = Signal(QImage)


class AsyncImageResponseRunnable(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signaller = Signaller()
        self.done = self.signaller.done

    def run(self):
        image = QImage(400, 400, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        image.fill('red')
        self.done.emit(image)


class AsyncImageResponse(QQuickImageResponse):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        runnable = AsyncImageResponseRunnable()
        runnable.done.connect(self.handle_done)
        pool = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        pool.start(runnable)

    def handle_done(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.finished.emit()
    
    def textureFactory(self):
        return QQuickTextureFactory.textureFactoryForImage(self.image)


class AsyncImageProvider(QQuickAsyncImageProvider):
    def requestImageResponse(self, image_id, requested_size):
        return AsyncImageResponse()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    
    engine.addImageProvider('async_test', AsyncImageProvider())
    
    engine.load('test.qml')
    app.exec()
```

```js
//test.qml

import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 1200
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Image {
        source: 'image://async_test/test'
    }
}
```

This causes a segmentation fault—and some of the time, immediately beforehand, I get this error message:

```
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: No such signal QObject::finished()
```

At first glance, this seems like it would be related to the `self.finished.emit()` line. However:

1. `QQuickImageResponse` defines the [`finished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickimageresponse.html#finished) signal, and
2. I get the same error message *even when I comment out* `self.finished.emit()`, which seems to indicate something internal must be attempting to call it.

So, what am I missing here? How do I avoid the segmentation fault and get my asynchronous image provider functional?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough experience with QML, but, in any case, you don't need to define existing signals for inheritance, and even if it was the case, you'd get an `AttributeError`: you're trying to emit `finished()` from a `QQuickImageResponse` subclass, which already has that signal, so that's not the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [reported this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1826) in case it was a bug, and one of the maintainers realized that the issue is that the `AsyncImageResponse` gets immediately deleted. The workaround for this is to hold a reference to it in the `AsyncImageProvider`:

```
class AsyncImageProvider(QQuickAsyncImageProvider):
    def requestImageResponse(self, image_id, requested_size):
        self.response = AsyncImageResponse()
        return self.response
```

They've also proposed a [change](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/pyside/pyside-setup/+/396971) that may make this unnecessary in the future.